# Realm object getting invalidated in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, realm

well i have a list of Contacts(Model) that i have . And that list is list of realm Objects . And i get those objects from realm like

```
    public static List<Contact> getAllTazligenContacts(Context context) {
    Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(context);
    return realm.where(Contact.class)
            .equalTo("isTazligenContact", true)
            .findAll();
    }
```

Now the problem is that i am calling an asynctask and i am using this list in that class like. It took me an hour to find out that the problem was with my realmObjects because in my asynctask

```
public class AsyncCallContacts extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Contact>> {

private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(mContext, null, getString(R.string.getting_contacts));
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected List<Contact> doInBackground(String... params) {
  //Some task (realm objectList is used)
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<Contact> result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    dialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.finishing_up));       
}
}
```

The problem is that i debugged the app and the list seems fine when i am in onPreExecute but the moment i enter onBackground my list gets invalidated i.e on every index it says "Illegel state exception or invalid object".
I did some searching and found out that maybe the thread deletes or invalidates the objects . So my question is how do i solve this . How do i prevent my realm list from getting invalidated ?? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Realm, RealmResult & RealmObject can not be passed across threads, when you use RealmObjects in AsyncTask, you are moving them to other thread which is why you are getting invalided objects.

You can use any of the following solutions,

- Keep all the operations on the same thread
- Get the RealmObjects in background thread
- Copy RealmObjects to non Realm model class and use it for your operations